# Does standard C++11 guarantee that std::async(std::launch::async, func) launches func in separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, c++14

Does standard C++11 guarantee that `std::async(std::launch::async, func)` launches function in separate thread?

Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++ 2016-07-12: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf

**1. On the one hand**, C++11-Standard says that if the thread can not be created, then there is an error. This ensures the creation of a new thread (in the absence of errors).

> § 30.6.8
>
> 6
>
> **Throws: system_error if** policy == launch::async and the
>   implementation is **unable to start a new thread.**
>
> 7 Error conditions:
>
> (7.1) — **resource_unavailable_try_again — if** policy == launch::async
>   and the system is **unable to start a new thread**.

And documentation says: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch

> std::launch::async    a new thread is launched to execute the task
>   asynchronously

**2. On the other hand**, it is written that the thread can be **potentially** created. Those, is not necessary that thread should be created.

> § 30.6.8
>
> 1 The function template async provides a mechanism to launch a
>   function **potentially in a new thread** and provides the result of the
>   function in a future object with which it shares a shared state.

And here written **as if in a new thread**, does it mean not necessary in new separate thread?

> § 30.6.8
>
> (3.1)
>
> — if policy & launch::async is non-zero — calls INVOKE (DECAY_COPY
>   (std::forward(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward(args))...)
>   (20.14.2, 30.3.1.2) **as if in a new thread** of execution
>   represented by a thread object with the calls to DECAY_COPY () being
>   evaluated in the thread that called async. Any return value is stored
>   as the result in the shared state. Any exception propagated from the
>   execution of INVOKE (DECAY_COPY (std::forward(f)), DECAY_COPY
>   (std::forward(args))...) is stored as the exceptional result in
>   the shared state. The thread object is stored in the shared state and
>   affects the behavior of any asynchronous return objects that reference
>   that state.

When used `std::async(std::launch::async, func)` then does standard C++11 guarantee that `func()` will be executed in separate thread, or it can be executed in the same thread that called async?

Comment: I read "as if in a new thread" to mean "as if you had called `std::thread(func)`"

Comment: I take "as if" to mean that the observable behaviour is as if you were in a new thread. For instance, thread-local variables would be initialized and destroyed.

Comment: Doesn't look the it guarantees a thread will be spawned but it looks to guarantee that the behavior of the program will be as if you did.  It's probably worded that way to allow some clever optimizations.

Comment: What if no thread is needed, eg if IO completion ports are used? In all languages a `future` or `async` feature allows the application to start an asynchronous operation and process its result when it returns. That doesn't mean that a thread will be used, or that the thread will be a new one. With real asynchronous operations (typically IO) you may not need a thread at all. If the implementation uses threadpools, you may get an idle thread from the pool instead of starting a new one.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  Yes, may be you are right, may be it can use already created thread from OS/C++-runtime thread-pool, if it uses IO Completion Ports (Proactor design pattern). But question is not "whether or not a new thread will be created", but question is "will be `func()` executed in the thread another than thread that called `async()`"? Those, does this guarantee that I can occupy two available CPU-cores by using `std::launch::async` to accelerate my programm, on condition `if (std::thread::hardware_concurrency() >= 2)`?

Comment: @Alex: Even if you create two separate `std::thread` objects, there's no guarantee that they'll be executed on separate cores. That is not something the specification can *promise*.

Comment: "as if" means your program can't tell what "really" happens.

Comment: @Alex C++ Has no concept of CPU cores whatsoever. A thread in the C++ abstract machine need not be implemented as a real hardware or OS thread. The abstract machine may indeed have its own pseudo threading system that all really runs in one thread. Also, doing a check for `(std::thread::hardware_concurrency() >= 2)` is a really bad idea, as an implementation is allowed to always return 0 for hardware_concurrency even if it in fact can run many threads, simply if it doesn't know, or the answer is complicated (NUMA etc). C++ Only ever guarantees observable behavior, that does not include speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two key statements here are:

> as if in a new thread of execution represented by a `thread` object
>
> The `thread` object is stored in the shared state and affects the behavior of any asynchronous return objects that reference that state.

"As if" means it must behave exactly as if it had created a `std::thread` object for this function. Which means that all side effects of the creation of a `std::thread` must also happen.

That being said, if you combine `launch::async` with `launch::deferred`, then the implementation decides whether to launch a new thread or defer it to an existing one. So it's only `launch::async` alone that requires a new thread.

Comment: Followup question. How do implementations handle a std::launch::deferred if it decides to defer to an existing thread? Does it have some algorithm to decide when to push it's stack frame onto the stack (is it deterministic)? Sorry if that question doesn't make sense, I am new to asynchronous stuff.

Comment: @TylerLewis: The standard makes it clear that all of that is implementation defined. If you use `deferred` by itself, then it gets run only when you try to access the `future`. But if you use both `async` and `deferred`, the implementation is in complete control about scheduling the execution of the function.